# Adjust application controls to fit window size

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to adjust the **height** of the controls: `trvMenu`, `StackPanel (Grid.Column="1")`, `StackPanel(Grid.Column="3")`, and **height+width** of: `tabControl` (width to what's left). I just need them to fit the size of the window of the application when it's running, like full screen, for example. Here's the xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="DiagramDesigner.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    ...
                    <TreeView Name="trvMenu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="312" 
                         ...                                                   
                    </TreeView>
                ...
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                        ...
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                ...
                <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" Grid.Column="2" SelectionChanged="tabDynamic_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    ...
                </TabControl>
                <StackPanel  Grid.Column="3">
                ...
                </StackPanel>
            ...
```

Comment: Remove all the explicit absolute values, such as `Width`, `Height` and `Margin`.

Comment: Did, no change for StackPanel Grid.Column="1" and tabControl.. @HighCore

Comment: also remove horizontal and vertical alignment setter tags.

Comment: Still no change :( I need those 4 controls to adjust just to the height of the window, but "tabControl" to adjust also to the width it has left @Sivasubramanian

Comment: You have placed the child controls in grid. Set the grid column's height and row's width to "AUTO".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to first build a grid according to the structure of the application, and each column or row that need to be adjusted to the window size should have:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        ...
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        ...
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

and

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       ...
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
       ...
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```